# Alert for possible thread protection

Tags: discussion

Please monitor this question/ thread

[People pathologically hoard so much cash that they impoverish the entire nation](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/17053/61)

It possibly approaches a situation where it will need to be protected.

Since I have posted an answer on the thread, as a matter of principle I would not want to be the one to decide on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread has been protected by denesp. I guess we can consider this to be solved.